# Magento 2 : Error/Success message won't remove from page after refresh once display

Tags: magento2, messages, global-messages

After display `success/error` message like "Item Added in cart" it won't remove from the page after refreshing the page. I am using Magento CE 2.0.7 version. Any one have the solution of this issue, please reply.

Also in login page `error` message won't display and after login success in next time login failure message will display on other page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been addressed and fixed in the latest version of Magento 2.

If you have not found any solution yet, just upgrade the Magento. This will fix the problem.

I have tried it for Magento 2.1.6, which I upgraded to Magento 2.1.9.

Comment: I am on 2.4.2 EE and the bug is still present.

Answer (score 0):

at  below repository people talking about cookie restriction mode issue for that

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5301

You can idea about that what is cookie restriction mode and how can you enable  or disable that in below link

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/cookie-restriction-mode.html

This is what I can help you for this problem

Comment: We already test all these, but not working

Answer (score 0):

there is a cookie record called "mage-messages". After deleting it, the old message won't be shown again.

I used the following code to remove it programmatically

```
...
private $_cookieManager;
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
) {
    ...
    $this->_cookieManager = $cookieManager;
}
...
private function _deleteMessage() {        
    $this->_cookieManager->deleteCookie('mage-messages');
}
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: And when should I call this _deleteMessage(), so that it calls on every reload or when the user navigates to a different page?