# Remove success message after show

Tags: addtocart, magento-2.0.7, messages, global-messages

I custom add to cart module on Magento 2 and keep message like Magento core.

```
if (!$this->_checkoutSession->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
    if (!$this->cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
        $message = __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
    }
    return $this->goBack(null, $product);
}
```

After add to cart success, it return message "Product name add to cart success".
But when I access to another page, that message still display.

Ex: I clicked add to cart, when it was loading, I quickly clicked to cart(checkout/cart). Success message was display at there. How can I remove that message, I just want it display one time at product(where click add to cart) page. I use Magento 2.0.7

Comment: this is magento bug..

Comment: Really! I don't think so.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135760/magento-2-error-success-message-wont-remove-from-page-after-refresh-once-disp

Comment: @mp196 yep bro, I tried follow answer on that question but it did not work. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Update]**

After all, I found a solution for this problem. It's made me sweat too much.

Message was inited at **messages.phtml** on Magento_Theme package(module-theme\view\frontend\templates\messages.phtml).

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' },attr:{class:((messages().messages && messages().messages.length > 0)?'messages block __caution mB30':'')}" class="">
    <p class="caution_text" data-bind="html: message.text, visible:message.text!='One or more input exceptions have occurred.'"></p>
</div>
```

So I think we have to remove message after it display. So I override magento theme and add this script end of messages.phtm file. It works like a charm.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/jquery-storageapi'], function($) {
        var storage = $.initNamespaceStorage('mage-cache-storage').localStorage;
        storage.remove('messages');
    });
</script>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I add tag 2.0.7 above

Comment: I am using 2.1.3 and it has the same problem

Comment: Was my answer help you fix it?

Comment: no it doesn't work on my version of Magento

Comment: Nope, the solution is not working...

Comment: This worked for me on 2.2.2

Comment: how can I change its location to beneath the short description or add to cart?

Answer (score 2):

For remove message in Magento 2 try this in phtml or js file:

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/jquery-storageapi'], function($) {
    $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually messages are taken from the messages container and put into a cookie named "mage-messages" here: \Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin

So I was able to rework this cookie by resetting it with my custom message.

Your business logic may differ if you want to merge your message with the existing one. Just fine tune `$messages` to your need.

In my case, I needed to clean all messages and replace them with a custom error message. See below:

```
$publicCookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata();
$publicCookieMetadata->setDurationOneYear();
$publicCookieMetadata->setPath('/');
$publicCookieMetadata->setHttpOnly(false);
$publicCookieMetadata->setSameSite('Strict');

$messages = [
    [
        'type' => 'error',
        'text' => __('Product cannot be added to the wishlist yet. Please log in or create an account in order to be able to add items to your wishlist.'),
    ],
];

$this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
    MessagePlugin::MESSAGES_COOKIES_NAME,
    json_encode($messages),
    $publicCookieMetadata
);
```

Magento EE 2.4.2