# Remove notification messages on refresh

Tags: magento2, messages, success-message, notification

Sometimes the notification messages don't get disappear on page reload or when I navigate to the different page.

Is there some kind of `timeout` for the notification message or some session cookies?

I followed this link

> [Magento 2 : Error/Success message won't remove from page after refresh once display](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135760/magento-2-error-success-message-wont-remove-from-page-after-refresh-once-disp)

But where should I put this code so that `_deleteMessage` call every time when the page reloads or user navigates to a different page.

This issue is more prominent in `iPhone devices safari browser`.

This is my code in `messages.js`

```
  this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text')[_.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text').length-1];
  this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });
  if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }
  customerData.set('messages', {messages: ""});
  $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
```

On further debugging, My code randomly breaks anywhere due to `WebAPI socket` error on console js debugging.

So this `WebAPI socket` error doesn't let this `cookie` clear.
This issue is intermittent.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had this issue once. disabling the Customer Notification cache solved my issue

Comment: @PhilippSander How to disable the Customer Notification cache

Comment: @PhilippSander got it from admin panel

Comment: @summu: I am also facing the same issue in iPhone (safari), can you please let me know how you fix it

Comment: @PurushotamSharma added my answer, it was my only option to use setInterval, i know its a hacky solution

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I resolved it using setInterval,

```
    return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: []
    },

    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        $('#validation-login-cust').html('');
        $('#valid-promo-cart').html('');
        try {
            var message = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            var textMessage =  JSON.parse(message[0]["text"]);
            if (textMessage['type'] === "inline"){
                $(textMessage["selector"]).text(textMessage["message"]).css('color', 'red');
            }

            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            customerData.set('messages', {messages: ""});
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');

        }catch (e) {

            $('#validation-login-cust').html('');
            $('#valid-promo-cart').html('');
            var messageText = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text')[_.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text').length-1];
            if (messageText) {
                if (messageText["text"].trim() == "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.") {
                    this.cookieMessages = 'OOps! Something went wrong, Please try again later or refresh the page.';
                } else {
                    this.cookieMessages = messageText;
                }
            }
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }
        }
        var setCookieInterval = setInterval(function()
        {
            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            YX_UI_UTIL.eraseCookie("mage-messages");

        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(setCookieInterval); }, 10000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where did you added above code

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this problem where notification messages persist across refreshed pages here are some tips that might help you resolve the problem.

- I first noticed this problem with Magento 2.4.1
- I mostly notice it on my development and staging servers

  - These servers are not in production mode

If you look at `magento-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js` you will see where these notification messages are read from the `mage-messages` cookie and passed to the backend for display.

You will notice that the function cleans up the `mage-messages` cookie

```
    $.mage.cookies.set('mage-messages', '', {
        samesite: 'strict',
        domain: ''
    });
```

If you add a console info log here, you can see that this executes with every page refresh. However, if you monitor the `mage-messages` cookie in the console you can sometimes see the cookie being set, deleted, and set again. This leads to the cookie persisting to the next page.

Whether this has to do with delays in the backend often seen on slower servers i.e. development / development mode or it's a new 2.4 bug I am not sure.

One way to ensure that the cookie is reset after being processed is to add another cleanup function to the `prepareMessageForHtml` function. Note this function is only present in 2.4.x

```
        // Bug hunting cookie cleanup for persistent frontend notification messages
        //
        //
        (function CookieCleanup(i) {
          setTimeout(function() {

              if ($.mage.cookies.get('mage-messages') !=='' )
              {
                  // cleanup
                  $.mage.cookies.set('mage-messages', '', {
                      samesite: 'strict',
                      domain: ''
                  });
                  console.info('Debug Cookie cleanup in progress...');
              }

              // keep on scrubbin'...
              if (--i) CookieCleanup(i);

          }, 3000)
        })(3);
```

In summary if you are seeing this message during development on 2.4.x try going to production mode with all caches enabled first. Debug further by adding console logs to `messages.js`.

Comment: Please fix `magento-theme/view/frontendweb/js/view/messages.js` to `magento-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js` in your answer

Comment: @paj Could you please update this and include the entire prepareMessageForHtml() function with your code solution? It isn't clear at all what you are saying here.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this issue in magento 2.4, have a look at my solution, which is very similar to one using setInterval above, but using setTimeout, also the js is a bit different in magento 2.4

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5301#issuecomment-1028756896

Comment: I have the same issue but on the admin page, how can I solve it? do you know?